# How to run Rails snippets shared on the internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to reproduce a [rails bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34622),

I have a [rails snippet](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34622#issuecomment-444492696) to do so, but I don't know how to run it.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  gem "activerecord", "5.1.6"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :company_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end

  create_table :companies, force: true do |t|
  end
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :company
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :users
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_pluck
    company = Company.create
    user = company.users.create

    assert_equal [[user.id, company.id]], User.where(company_id: company.id).includes(:company).pluck(:id, :'companies.id')
  end
end
```

**How can I test this snippet locally?**

Should I just put it in a .rb file and run it with ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a ruby file from terminal with:

```
ruby path/to/ruby_file.rb
```

However the code snippet you give above doesn't actually do anything from what I can see, it simply sets up the classes ready to do stuff with them.

After looking at your bug link, you will need to create a new Rails application (just try `rails new project_name` from console), and then setup the models as they've described in the snippet.